# Generating specific output patterns from a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

Given a Python tuple

```
products = (a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
```

I seek to generate a new tuple/list from 'products', but according to specific patterns:

1. all possible chronological combinations to make pairs e.g. ab, ac (& so on...) af, ag, bc, and so on
2. similar to #1, but making sets of three and making sure the increment change to either side of the 'middle' product is equal e.g. abc, bcd (& so on...) *and* ace, bdf, ceg
3. sets of four, again making sure that the increment change is equal to either side (and between) middle products e.g. abcd, bcde (& so on…) *and* aceg

From asking around and reading on Python's site, the itertools.combinations() function seemed a step in the right direction. But given the specific patterns being sought for creation, seems more than just that function in its standard usage form is needed. Any suggestions?

P.S. the *average* actual tuple is several times longer than the example above (I'll have about 40 tuples total), and some 'products' within each will expire/drop out and new ones added every few weeks, so manually entering the combinations into new tuples isn't in keeping with the aims of automation.

Comment: Please add your code, we can't help you if you don't show what you have done.

Comment: Jarvis, I don't have any code written yet, at least not for these patterns.

Comment: Martineau, I asked for suggestions, not full-on code writing. How is this question substantially different than hundreds of other code writing questions on SO?

Comment: What does a "chronological combination" of *letters* mean?

Comment: No, but many of them get closed (or should have been). stakcoverflow is also not a tutorial site. You need to do some more reading and research...not start asking others to write code for you (or tell you how to write the code, which is about the same thing).

Comment: Scott, that means a combination can't be a 'permutation' like the itertools.permutation() function does, where reordering the items is allowed e.g. ca, ed, ga, and so on

Comment: @Martineau - Oh really? Kind of like you've done in other threads (e.g. 'Tkinter how to change TTK button to bold?')?

Comment: @CB001: I don't think "chronological" means what you think it means. "relating to the establishment of dates and time sequences"

Answer (score 2):

Here's an obvious lazy way:

```
>>> products = 'abcdefg'
>>> for length in range(2, 5):
        for step in range(1, 42):
           for start in range(42):
               x = products[start : start+length*step : step]
               if len(x) == length:
                   print x,
        print

ab bc cd de ef fg ac bd ce df eg ad be cf dg ae bf cg af bg ag
abc bcd cde def efg ace bdf ceg adg
abcd bcde cdef defg aceg
```

You can get rid of the `if len(x) == length:` check if you replace my `42` with properly calculated stop values.

Comment: Where on earth did 42 come from?

Comment: @ScottHunter "Hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy" ring a bell?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Plus the OP said something about size 40, so that felt about right.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner, where `n` is the case number:

```
[ products[i:i+j*n+1:j] for j in xrange(1,len(products)/n+1) for i in xrange(len(products)-j*(n-1)) if i+j*n<len(products) ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Scott!